# Showing Lebesgue Measurable Set is Measure Zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to show that given $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $A$ Lebesgue measurable and given that $m(A\cap [a,b]) < \frac{b-a}{2}$ for every $a<b$, that $A$ must have measure zero. I've been trying to use continuity of measure in some way, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Look for: Lebesgue density theorem... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem

Comment: @GEdgar How would I apply the theorem in this particular case? I'm having trouble seeing how to.

Comment: Look at ${1 \over \epsilon} \int_x^{x+\epsilon} 1_A = {1 \over \epsilon} m(A \cap [x,x+\epsilon]) $.

Comment: Your inequality shows that the set $A$ has density at most $1/2$ everywhere.   But we also know that it has density $1$ almost everywhere on $A$.  Therefore, $A$ has measure $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of outer Lebesgue measure (or by regularity, depending on how you define Lebesgue measure), given $\varepsilon>0$ there exist disjoint intervals $I_1,\ldots,I_r$, $I_\ell=(a_\ell,b_\ell)$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_\ell I_\ell$ and
$$
m(\bigcup_\ell I_\ell)<m(A)+\varepsilon. 
$$
So
\begin{align}
m(A)&\leq m(\bigcup_\ell I_\ell)<m(A)+\varepsilon= m(A\cap\bigcup_\ell I_\ell)+\varepsilon
=\sum_\ell m(A\cap(a_\ell,b_\ell))+\varepsilon\\[0.3cm]
&<\frac12\,\sum_\ell(b_\ell-a_\ell)+\varepsilon
=\frac12\,m(\bigcup_\ell I_\ell)+\varepsilon\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\frac12\,m(A)+\frac{3\varepsilon}2.
\end{align}
So
$$
m(A)\leq 3\varepsilon
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$, showing that $m(A)=0$.